# Efficient way to transpose a huge tab-delimited file (2.1TB) @ 8.5Kx39M

Tags: bash, transpose

I have a few gigantic tab-delimited files @ ~2.1 TB each, ~8.5 K rows, ~39.3M columns. The first column is all string (ID) of variable length, the rest are non-negative fixed precision decimals at three places beyond zero (i.e., each column after the ID is 5 characters long 0.000).

What is the most efficient way to transpose the file in a Linux machine with 256GB RAM? Ultimately, after the transpose, I want to chunk the files into 500K lines each so that I can start working on it. Hard drive is no problem, there is 70TB free space.

This is what I can come up with (which takes about 2.5 days per file). The problem is that each file has very slightly different numbers of rows and columns. I don't want to modify the scripts at every run. Alternatively, I could make a specialized C program just to do this, but I'm reluctant to do so.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=$1
mkdir temp-$i
cd temp-$i
echo "Splitting $i"
split -dl 1 -a 4 ../$i
echo "Transposing all lines"
for a in x???? ; do
    cat $a | sed 's/\t/\n/g' > $a.txt
    mv $a.txt $a
done
echo "Joining all columns"
# Here's where it gets really ugly:
paste x0000 x0001 ... x0999 > a.txt
paste x1000 x1001 ... x1999 > b.txt
paste x2000 x2001 ... x2999 > c.txt
paste x3000 x3001 ... x3999 > d.txt
paste x4000 x4001 ... x4999 > e.txt
paste x5000 x5001 ... x5999 > f.txt
paste x6000 x6001 ... x6999 > g.txt
paste x7000 x7001 ... x7999 > h.txt
paste x8000 x8001 ... x8499 > i.txt
paste ../colinfo-$i.txt a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt f.txt g.txt h.txt i.txt > ../tr-$i.txt
cd ../
rm -Rf temp-$i
```

Comment: Personally, I'd go for the dedicated C program. There are only 8K5 + one for the reader I/O threads needed, so you can keep your memory footpint low and use that for the diskbuffers. In other cases you'd have to design some tiling scheme, but sizeof (elem) == 6) looks nasty for tiling.

Comment: do you have a multi-processor machine? Can you run your pastes in the background and then use your systems utility to "bind" each bk-grnded process by PID? (your's is one place where a 2-4% gain actually turns into hours:-). There may be issues with writing to the same disk segment. gnu-parallel is good (I've heard), or you may want to look at full-bore multiprocessing platforms like hadoop. If this is a one off, then maybe you'll have to live with slow processing. Good luck.

Comment: @wildplasser: I might do that for the last resort.

Comment: @shellter: Well, I suppose I can use background processes, but it's hard for me to see the advantage. Thanks.

Comment: The C-solution would *at least* do all you need in *one pass* (well maybe a prepass to find the offsets of the second fields and the actual record count) For the rest, it would be *completely* I/O bound. Adding more CPU's  (more than say 3) would not make it any faster.

Comment: I thoroughly agree with you, wildplasser.

Comment: Do all rows have the same number of entries or are some elements missing?

Comment: All rows have the same number of entries, fortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The paste operations are killing your performance. How about just create as many files as you have columns and then using a single pass through the input file, write data to the column files. I. e.:

Input file:

```
ID     data1 data2 data3 .... data5000
94239  0.001 0.002 0.003 .... 5.000
43244  0.011 0.012 0.013 .... 5.010
```

Output files:

col0:

```
ID    94239   43244
```

col1:

```
data1 0.001   0.011
```

...another 4999 files here...

col5000:

```
data5000 5.000 5.010
```

Splitting the columns out can be done with this perl program:

```
#!perl -n

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path 'make_path';

$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\t";

my $colno = 0;
my $maxcol = 0;
while(my $col = <STDIN>) {
    $colno = 0 if $col =~ s/\n//;
    $colno++;
    my $path = join '/', $colno =~ /(\d{3})/g;
    if($colno > $maxcol) {
        make_path $path;
        $maxcol = $colno;
    }
    open my $OUT, '>>', "$path/col.tsv";
    print $OUT "$col\t";
    close $OUT;
}
```

(Untested!)

Then at the end just concatenate the files together:

```
cat col0 col1 ... col5000 > newfile.tsv
```

(`xargs` may be required.)

Comment: Okay, I am not aware of any good and fast solutions to split file by columns. Awk is definitely a no-no since it is really slow. Do I need a script in perl or python or etc? If we use cut, how can we know efficiently the number of columns a file has?

Comment: I've just noticed that there is 39 million columns (right?), so you'll get to create 39 million files. I'd still try this solution, but the many open and close operations required (because you can't keep 39 million files open) may turn out to be a bottleneck. Also, remember not to put all files in the same directory. Most file systems get extremely slow at some point, so create a reasonably deep hierarchy of directories to store the column files in (i. e. for column 102310442, just put it in ``102/310/442.tsv``.

Comment: Perl can be used to split the file by columns, but for obvious reasons, trying to split a whole line at a time will fail.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Alternatively, I may want to extract, say, 10K columns at a time. But I fail to see that this approach can be any faster.

Comment: I've just added an snippet that should split the columns. The reason that this approach should be faster is to avoid too many passes over the data. When you use paste, you'll get O(n^2) complexity. This has O(n). In other words, my approach will give you *two* passes over the data, where your approach will pass over the data many more times - ``x000`` is passed over 8500 times. Since there is ~40 million items in this file alone, you are effectively passing over ~400 billion items (rounding 8500 up to 10000) *for this file alone*.

Comment: Pardon me for being ignorant of how the paste work. If m is the number of rows, and n is the number of columns, regardless how you split the file (either by row or by column), the complexity is still O(mn), right? The paste program opens ~1000 file at once and the operation is done m/1000 times (in this case, 9 times). The paste will write n lines each operation. So, it's still O(mn). Perhaps this is not how paste works.

Comment: You are right. I overestimated the complexity - you are not pasting incrementally, but still - you'll get more passes over the data just by using the last paste command. But I have to admit that you are down to just three passes, so the question is if the many open and close operations in my example can make up for that. I doubt it.

Comment: If you can convert the file to fixed with, it is obvious that the transpose can be done in just one pass.

Comment: You're right. Your solution could be more elegant than mine, though. I hate modifying my script at every run. I guess there is ultimate way to speed up for this problem is a custom C program.

Comment: Converting the file to a fixed width might be a great idea in this case since only the IDs are of different length. I may pursue that direction. Thanks.

Comment: If it is only the first column that is variable length, then you should be able to get decent performance by writing a program that extracts one column at a time, simply by guessing where the next ``ID`` column is. The biggest concern is avoiding loading too many blocks from the file system, but seeking over 39M columns followed by seeking some 10-20 bytes in order to find the next column shouldn't really be a problem. Since there is ~8000 rows, scanning through each column one at a time (using seek) should result in buffering up some 8000 file system blocks, that the fs ought to keep in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/raw/master/transpose/transpose

```
cat table.csv | transpose -d , > transposed.csv
transpose -d '\t' table.tsv > transposed.tsv
```

This is a general tool, where you give the delimiter and the size of buffer to use.

It works by chopping table.csv into 10M chunks (can be adjusted with `-b` and should be in the order of FreeMem/NumberOfCores/10). These are then transposed in parallel (one per CPU core). Finally the transposed chunks are pasted together.

It assumes each line is a full CSV-record (i.e. quoted \n will not work).

Speed: 2.5 min for 3 GB CSV file 1000000x300 table.

Speed: 5 min for 3 GB CSV file 300x1000000 table.

Comment: How you run this file, as I don't know anything about perl. My input file is 'sample.txt' and is tab delimited. Output file is "output.txt", tab delimited

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to be working. It uses up a lot of ram, even when I set the bugger to 10G. I got the source from your gitlab page.

Comment: Can you please re-test the new version?

Answer (score 1):

Your files are very regular in sizes, so it is possible to seek the exactly position for data, and get transposed result with IO read/write operation in one time.

It just needs to cacluate the length of the first line, and the other lines are all numbers with 5 bytes.

```
Input File example:
ID  data1   data2   data3   data4   data5   data6   data7 ...
78028   0.185   0.146   0.910   0.458   0.223   0.853   0.215 ...
76877   0.049   0.486   0.313   0.777   0.599   0.197   0.676 ...
81636   0.055   0.640   0.081   0.477   0.713   0.866   0.308 ...
```

file offset of data '0.049'(target row=2, col=3) is: length(headerline)+length(eachdataline)*(col-2)+row*(5+1)

The following python codes work for my test data

```
#encoding=utf-8
import sys
from sys import argv
import os
import time

start = time.time()
def elapsed():
    return time.time() - start

def transpose(filepath):
    # calculate offset for header line
    header_item_offsets = []
    org_rowcnt, org_colcnt = 0, 0
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if org_rowcnt==0:
                headeritems = line[:-1].split('\t')     # remove \n, then split by \t
                org_colcnt = len(headeritems)
                offset = 0
                offset_headerline = len(line)      # + 1 #windows end with \r\n
                offset_dataline = org_colcnt*6    # +1 # windows end with \r\n
                for item in headeritems:
                    header_item_offsets.append(offset)
                    offset += len(item)+1
                # append one more offset for the last item
                header_item_offsets.append(offset)
            org_rowcnt += 1

    with open(filepath,'rb') as infile, open( filepath+'_transed.txt','w') as outfile:
        # transpose
        for row in xrange(org_colcnt):
            line = []
            for col in xrange(org_rowcnt):
                if col==0:
                    # data from header line
                    offset = header_item_offsets[row]
                    readsize = header_item_offsets[row+1] - header_item_offsets[row] - 1
                else:
                    # data from data line offset = header_offset + eachline_offset*(col-1) + row*6
                    offset = offset_headerline + offset_dataline*(col-1) + row*6
                    readsize = 5
                infile.seek(offset)
                line.append( infile.read(readsize) )
            outfile.write( '\t'.join(line) + '\n' )
            if row%10000==0:
                print "Generating row %d" % row

if __name__=="__main__":
    script, filepath = argv
    transpose(filepath)
    print "Running Time:\t", elapsed()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing every byte 4 times: split, sed, paste and final.

If we can avoid writing the bytes that many times, we will save time.

This script does the split and sed in one go.

And the paste and final in one go.

So you will only write the data to temporary space once.

For the final it uses the <() bash construct:

```
paste <(paste t{1..999}) <(paste t{1000..2000})
```

This will seek a lot, so if you can change the read-ahead of the disk, then that would be a very good idea. (blockdev --setra and --setfra)

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                         

use English;

while(<>) {
    s/,/\n/g;
    open(OUT,">","t$NR") or die;
    print OUT $_;
    close OUT;
}

my $nfiles = $NR;

@cmd = ("paste ");
my $last = 0;
for my $n (1..$nfiles) {
    if(not $n % 1000) {
    push @cmd, "<(paste t{".($last+1)."..".$n."})";
    $last = $n;
    }
}
if(not $last == $nfiles) {
    push @cmd, "<(paste t{".($last+1)."..".$nfiles."})";
}
system "bash -c '@cmd'";
```

Call with:

```
cat table | mysplit.pl | split -C 500000; rm t*
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I've solved this problem using a binary file trick. I first indexed the position of each line separator, then figured out the position of the first tab. Then, without doing seek, I computed the length of each ID. After this, I created a binary file and basically transpose the contents there. It's pretty fast.

Comment: Well, I'm reluctant to use regex at this point. I changed the script above with tr and it's a bit faster, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions so far are fast enough I believe this will be.

We know every row is 39.3M*(5+1) + a little. It is therefore relatively easy to find the exact starting position for every row. It will cost around 8.5k seeks+reads to do that.

Given the 8.5k startpositions we do:

```
for s (startpositions) {
    push r, record.init(s)
}
nrows = len(startpositions)

while (not finished) {
    for row (1..nrows-1) {
        print r[row].get(),"\t"
    }
    print r[nrows].get(),"\n"
}

class record:
init(position) {
    pos = position
}

get() {
    if values.empty and not end_of_line {
        seek pos
        buffer += read(1MB)
        pos += 1MB
        if buffer =~ s/\n.*// {
            end_of_line = true;
        }
        values = split /\t/, buffer
        buffer = pop values
    }
    return pop values
}
```

This way we only do 1 seek per 1 MB and we only read the file once and have no temporary files.

1 MB/record should cache in total 8.5 GB, so it ought to be safe to increase the 1 MB to 20 MB on 256GB machine, giving 1 seek per 20 MB data.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow temporary file like mzedeler suggests and want to stay  this worked for me:

```
inFile="bigTable.csv"
sep=","
outFile="bigTable.transposed.csv"

TMPWD=`mktemp -d --tmpdir=$TMPDIR transpose.XXXXXXXX`

prefix=$TMPWD/col

while read line; do
  cat \
    | mawk -vFS="$sep" -f  <(
      #generate AWK-code and print first entries to the temporary files
      echo $line \
        | mawk -vFS="$sep" -vprefix=$prefix '
            {
              printf("{")
              endCmd="END {"
              for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){
                file=sprintf(prefix"%05d",i)
                printf("%s",$i) > file
                printf("printf(\"%s%%s\",$%s) >> \"%s\"; ",FS,i,file)
                endCmd= endCmd""sprintf("printf(\"\\n\") >> \"%s\"; ",file)
              }
              endCmd=endCmd"}"
              printf("} ")
              print endCmd
            }
          '
    )
done < <( cat $inFile )

cat ${prefix}* > $outFile

rm -rf $TMPWD
```

Admittedly I only had a 12x25M, but with this it ran through in about 2min. I'm trying to avoid the for loop in AWK by including a code-generating step. The internal code is on the form:

```
{printf(",%s",$1) >> "tmp/col00001"; ... printf(",%s",$N) >> "tmp/col0000N"; }
END {printf("\n") >> "tmp/col00001"; ... printf("\n") >> "tmp/col0000N" }
```